# How to change one piece of code when can't pull master?

Tags: git

We have a production server which uses only `master` branch. We are in situation that our local master (yes it is our fault) is full of many commits and code we can't pull to server right know.

We need to change couple of lines of code on server.

Which way would you recommend? I figured out these two ways but I'm not sure about their safety:

1. Create a new branch on production server `master` branch, push it, then do some changes, pull back and switch to this branch.
2. Just edit it manually (there will be conflicts in future)
3. Other, better option?

Comment: Make best use of the commit ID. Simply go back to your commit ID, make hot-fix, push in new branch. Deploy. Finish. It is recommended to have a seperate PROD branch. You can have now and can cherrypick code easily.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't come up with a "nice" way to do this.  But, here is one approach:

First, create a new local branch from your current local `master`:

```
# from master
git branch master_backup
```

Next, fetch the latest changes from the remote, which should include the changes to the remote `master` branch:

```
git fetch origin
```

Then reset your local `master` to the remote branch via:

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```

At this point, your local `master` branch should be synched up with the current remote `master`, and also your previous local `master` has been backed up to `master_backup`.  Now, you may make your changes to `master` and push them:

```
# work work work
git add .
git commit -m 'hotfix for master'
git push origin master
```

Finally, to get back to the original state of your local `master` branch, you may hard reset it to the backup branch:

```
# from master
git reset --hard master_backup
```

At this point, if you don't want the backup `master` branch, you may delete it:

```
git branch -d master_backup
```

This is a verbose solution, but partly it has to do with that you are not able to follow the normal workflows for Git.  Ideally you should not allow your local branch to get so far out of sync with the remote version that you cannot push.  It is general good advice to sync as often as possible in Git.